# Why does make-frame automatically maximize new frames?

Tags: frames, fullscreen

FWIW, I'm on Mac OS X running this with `emacs -Q`:

```
GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0, NS appkit-1404.47 Version 10.11.6 (Build 15G1108)) of 2016-11-11
```

If I click the little "maximize" button I get a frame with the `(fullscreen . fullboth)` parameter.  According to ancient tradition, let us all praise Emacs' distinctive naming conventions.

From a maximized frame, I cannot get `(make-frame)` to create a non-maximized frame.  I've tried setting the `fullscreen`, `height`, and `width` options of `default-frame-alist`, and I've tried passing various combinations of the same into the `make-frame` function.  No joy.

What am I missing?

Comment: Show your code. The question is unclear so far. `make-frame` is to create a new frame, not to resize an existing frame. Are you saying that if you have one frame maximized you cannot create another (using `make-frame`)? Are you sure a frame was not created behind your maximized one? (Try `raise-frame` for it, if that's the case.)

Comment: Not really any code to show.  From a terminal, `emacs -Q`.  Click the button that maximizes the frame.  Then, in the scratch buffer, `(make-frame) C-x C-e`.  It creates a new frame, but the new frame is also maximized.  I'm seeking what options I need to pass in to the `(make-frame)` function to get a new frame that is NOT also maximized

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this with Emacs 25.1.1 downloaded from https://emacsformacosx.com/ (built September 17, 2016).  Without any user configuration, I launch Emacs.app on OSX 10.6.8.  I click on the green button twice -- once to make it the full length of the frame, and a second time to make it the full width of the frame.  I kill the `*GNU Emacs*` with Command-k, I type `(make-frame)` in the `*scratch*` buffer and type `C-x C-e`.  The new frame is the default small size in the upper-left corner of the screen.

Comment: On OSX 10.11.6, I change the recipe slightly and call `M-x toggle-frame-maximized` and get the same result as my previous comment by using the same steps (except for no green button pressing in this example).  On 10.11.6, the green button makes the frame full screen, not just maximized.

Comment: If, however, on 10.11.6, I hit the green button and make it full screen, then I get the same result as the original poster -- i.e., the new frame is also full screen (probably because I'm in full-screen mode, which seems like the behavior I would expect, although I've only thought about it for a few minutes).

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for checking that.  I've gotta run some errands, will update the post to clarify when I'm back later